# Is Array[String] not a subclass of Seq[String] in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, scala-collections, seq

I wrote a method that accepts objects of all subclasses of Seq[String]. Unfortunately it won't accept an object of the type Array[String]. Is Array[String] not a subclass of Seq[String]?

```
scala> def test[T <: Seq[String]](x: T) = {}
test: [T <: Seq[String]](x: T)Unit

scala> val data = "This is a test string"
data: java.lang.String = This is a test string

scala> test(data.split(" "))
<console>:10: error: inferred type arguments [Array[java.lang.String]] do not conform to method test's type parameter bounds [T <: Seq[String]]
              test(data.split(" "))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, `Array[String]` translates to regular JVM arrays, like the ones you see in Java: `String[]`.

The reason why you see all the operations on `Array[String]` that you see on other Scala `Seq` collections is that there is an [implicit conversion](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef%24.html) from `Array[T]` to [`ArrayOps[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps.html).

Do this:

```
def test[T <% Seq[String]](x: T) = {}
```

This is called a *view bound*. It means that `T` should either be a subtype of `Seq[String]` or there should exist an implicit conversion in scope which converts `T` into a `Seq[String]`. Behind the scenes, the compiler actually adds an implicit parameter to `test`, so this method becomes:

```
scala> def test[T <% Seq[String]](x: T) = {}
test: [T](x: T)(implicit evidence$1: T => Seq[String])Unit
```

This `implicit evidence$1` is the function which now acts as the implicit conversion from `T` to `Seq[String]` within the body of the method.

Comment: explain the work of the view bound a bit and this answer will explain all important things going on here.

Comment: Very enlightening. I am still new to Scala and view bounds are new to me. I will get into that. Thanks for your rapid reply.

Answer (score 5):

The sources (or the [API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html)) state, that `Array` is defined as

```
final class Array[T] extends Serializable with Cloneable
```

That is, it is not a subtype of `Seq`. However, the docs also mention an implicit conversion [`WrappedArray`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray.html), where the latter is a subset of `Seq`.